# Django manager first() vs Model.objects.all()[:1]

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I would like to know if [`first()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#first) is the same as [limiting querysets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/#limiting-querysets).

Is `Model.objects.first()` the same as `Model.objects.all()[:1]` in speed?

You've to remember that `first()` is the same as `Model.objects.all()[0]`, so my thoughts are that they aren't the same, but then I don't understand why we have a handy method as `first()`.

Comment: You can append `.query`  to the end of both of them to see what they output. `.first()` and `.all()[0]` do not do the exact same thing. and `[:1]` returns a queryset still, not an instance

Comment: [Have a look at the source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/60e52a047e55/django/db/models/query.py#L544)

Comment: `.query` will not work with `first()`, has to be a Queryset. Anyway, my dudes are solved, thanks.

Comment: Ah of course... more evidence that they're not the same thing :)..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Model.objects.first()` returns one instance or `None`, while `Model.objects.all()[:1]` returns a slice of the queryset, with zero or one instances.  Here is `first()`'s source code from Django 1.10:

```
def first(self):
    """
    Returns the first object of a query, returns None if no match is found.
    """
    objects = list((self if self.ordered else self.order_by('pk'))[:1])
    if objects:
        return objects[0]
    return None
```

Answer (score 6):

Regarding speed. Using timeit module in ipython I found:

```
In [11]: %timeit rompepc.models.SampleModel.objects.all()[:1][0]                  
1000 loops, best of 3: 326 µs per loop                                       

In [12]: %timeit rompepc.models.SampleModel.objects.first()                    
1000 loops, best of 3: 464 µs per loop
```

There is still a difference when you try to access to fields

```
In [14]: %timeit rompepc.models.SampleModel.objects.all()[:1][0].sample_field  
1000 loops, best of 3: 323 µs per loop                                         

In [15]: %timeit rompepc.models.SampleModel.objects.first().sample_field       
1000 loops, best of 3: 461 µs per loop
```

Have in mind that you would need to validate length before using the indexed version. Answering your question, it seems like is not the same.

Note: There're only two records in the model with a single char field. Database is SQLite3. It may behaves different with more records, fields and another DB engine