# 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'pk' in "bulk_update"

Tags: django, django-models, orm, django-orm

I have model of Professor and need to "bulk_update". I have to do this in 2 requests from my DB.
But i have exception ('QuerySet' object has no attribute 'pk'). If i use get i have another exception(get() returned more than one Professor).

My model.

```
 class Professor(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    age = models.IntegerField(default=18)
    class Meta:
        indexes = [models.Index(fields=['first_name'])]
```

My code

```
def update_professor_first_names(first_name_updates: List[NameUpdate]):
    prof_id = [id for id, name in first_name_updates]
    prof = Professor.objects.filter(id__in=prof_id)
    tmp = []
    for prof_id, new_first_name in first_name_updates:
        prof.first_name = new_first_name
        tmp.append(prof)
    Professor.objects.bulk_update(tmp, ['first_name'])
```

Can you give me some advices about it?

Comment: Ye the qs object doesn't have a pk, each instance of the qs does though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `prof` is a `QuerySet` of `Professor`s, not a single `Professor`, hence it is non sensical to write `prof.first_name = new_first_name`, and it will also result in `tmp` being a *list* of the same `QuerySet` repeated multiple times.

You should look up the `Professor` object, and assign it accordingly, so:

```
def update_professor_first_names(first_name_updates: List[NameUpdate]):
    prof_id = [id for id, name in first_name_updates]
    profs = {p.id: p for p in Professor.objects.filter(id__in=prof_id)}
    tmp = []
    for prof_id, new_first_name in first_name_updates:
        prof = profs[prof_id]
        prof.first_name = new_first_name
        tmp.append(prof)
    Professor.objects.bulk_update(tmp, ['first_name'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `.first()` or `[:1]` to the end of your query like so:

`prof = Professor.objects.filter(id__in=prof_id).first()`
or

`prof = Professor.objects.filter(id__in=prof_id)[:1]`

This way, you can do `prof.first_name = new_first_name`

Comment: The difference between .first() and [:1] is explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42621402/django-manager-first-vs-model-objects-all1